# How to capture google earth desktop program to bmp file?

Tags: winapi

How to capture google earth desktop program window to bmp file? I used printwindow function, but it only captures controls, region with planet is empty. Google earth can be minimized, or hidden with other windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to have a look at Google Earth APIs, if you want to do that programmatically

http://code.google.com/apis/earth/

Comment: I can use api's. But i need local client, and i have to integrate 2 Google earth windows into one application with different zoom. COM API doesn't support it, maybe you have better solution to integrate two windows? Can plugin for browser be configured to work with local data?

Comment: @INs: I'm sorry, I only played wery quickly with their API, not sure if/how it's possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On the menu in Google Earth, use:

File -> Save -> Save image